# How do I make mentioning a member optional within a command?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I've created a code that sends the gif of a hug on command and specifies who it's to, however, I also want to make it optional to mention a member.

the current code is:

```
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member):
    username = ctx.message.author.display_name
    embed = discord.Embed(title = (f'{username} has sent a hug to {member}!'), description = ('warm, fuzzy and comforting <3'), color = 0x83B5E3)
    image = random.choice([(url1), (url2),....(url10)])
    embed.set_image(url=image)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I want to change it so that if the author uses the command and *doesn't* mention the member, the command still works, and sends one of the gifs instead. Do I have to create an if statement?

Additionally, if it is possible, how do I change it so that the member's display name is used just like how the author's display name is used?

I've tried doing something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member):
    username = ctx.message.author.display_name
    name = member.display_name
    embed = discord.Embed(title = (f'{username} has sent a hug to {name}!'), description = ('warm, fuzzy and comforting <3'), color = 0x83B5E3)
    image = random.choice([(url1), (url2),...(url10)])
    embed.set_image(url=image)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `member` argument to `None` by default. If you invoke your command without mentionning anyone, `member` will have `None` as value and the `if member` statement won't be triggered.

Also, by defining `member` as a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object in the function's arguments, you'll be able to access the mentionned member's informations.

Here's how you use it :

```py
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.author} has sent a hug to {member}!',
                              description='warm, fuzzy and comforting <3',
                              color=0x83B5E3)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x83B5E3)
        image = random.choice([(url1), (url2),....(url10)])
        embed.set_image(url=image)

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thank you! If I use your code exactly, I get an error saying that embed was referenced before it was defined. To get around this, I added the 'embed = discord.Embed(title = title, ...)' under the elif & else statements. It works perfectly fine, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing so?

Comment: I've edited my answer, it should be more efficient ^^