# How do i make a command in Discord.py that you @ a user and it gives that user a hug

Tags: command, discord.py

Please help I just want it to say "Hugs to @user"

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have a look at these, they might answer your question: [How do I make mentioning a member optional within a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860335/14420546), [Discord.py get user object from id/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500251/14420546), [discord.py Mention user by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64723445/14420546).

Comment: Show some efforts next time when you ask a question, this is not a "find someone to write code platform".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint, not a free code for you platform, write your own code. Anyways here's how to ping users.

```py
@bot.command() #the bot is a variable you can assign it to anything
async def ping(ctx)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}")
```

Comment: `ctx.author.mention` may possibly be a better way to mention `ctx.author` rather than having to grab the id.